# Battery light has been flickering for about a year now after replacing alternator and battery

Tags: electrical, alternator

After replacing both alternator and battery, I noticed the light flickering quickly for about a week, took it back to shop and they said everything looks fine.  a year later it is still flickering.  I am getting scared the whole electrical system is going to die on me.  I have to ask can this just be a stupid dummy light issue?  I brought it to advanced auto last month they said the charge on both battery and alternator is fine.  I seemed to notice the more things I have on the more it stays solid then flickers again. If i have nothing on it still flickers then goes off for a while then flickers again. maybe 1 or 2 days a week no flickering.  it is a Honda civic LX and it is a rebuilt alternator they put in. They said it would cost me a lot of money to figure out where it's coming from if the light doesn't stay on continuously! Help!  ty

Comment: Sounds like it is just a crap remanufactured alternator. I'd monitor the output voltage at the alternator and check the alternator lamp circuit. I've had this happen on aftermarket remans before. Ended up replacing it with an OE alternator.

Comment: Agree it is a poorly remanufactured alternator.